# How to get DefaultInstance when bootstrapping SQL Server 2005 Express

Tags: sql-server-2005, wix, bootstrapper

I'm able to install SQL Server 2005 Express with the bootstrapper, but I can't seem to be able to install the default instance.

I have tried

```
<Property Id="SQLInstance" Value="MSSQLSERVER" />
<ExePackage Id="SQL2005Express" DisplayName="SQL Server 2005 EXPRESS" Cache="yes" Compressed="yes"
            InstallCondition="not SqlInstanceKeyFound"
            DetectCondition="SqlInstanceKeyFound"
            PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes" Name="SQLEXPR.EXE" SourceFile="$(var.ThirdToolsSrc)\SQLEXPR.EXE"
            InstallCommand="/qn ADDLOCAL=All SECURITYMODE=SQL [SqlVariable] DISABLENETWORKPROTOCOLS=0 INSTANCENAME=[SQLInstance]">
    <ExitCode Value ="3010" Behavior="forceReboot" />
</ExePackage>
```

This will create an instance `[MACHINENAME]\SQLEXPRESS`, I tried without specifying the `InstanceName` parameter but got the same result.

Looking at this [page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2006/09/20/configuring-sql-express-during-installation.aspx), I don't see what I can change to be able to add the default instance.

I want to have the `DefaultInstance` to be `[MachineName]` only

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you setting up a program to install SQL Server 2005 in 2014? You know 2005 isn't even in mainstream support anymore, right? Did you try `InstanceName=[MSSQLServer]`, [as documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259(v=sql.90).aspx)?

Comment: It's an old application that I was asked to create a bootstrapper, that's why 2005 is used.  I did use MSSQLServer, but not in brackets though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured what was causing the problem, event though it seems a bit weird to me, but I was able to get the required result.

ORIGINAL CODE

```
<ExePackage Id="SQL2005Express" DisplayName="SQL Server 2005 EXPRESS" Cache="yes" Compressed="yes"
            InstallCondition="not SqlInstanceKeyFound"
            DetectCondition="SqlInstanceKeyFound"
            PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes" Name="SQLEXPR.EXE" SourceFile="$(var.ThirdToolsSrc)\SQLEXPR.EXE"
            InstallCommand="/qn ADDLOCAL=All SECURITYMODE=SQL [SqlVariable] DISABLENETWORKPROTOCOLS=0 INSTANCENAME=[SQLInstance]">
```

MODIFIED CODE (Working)

I didnèt think that the order of the parameters were important , but it seems that they are.